# Can I open tecplot files in paraview?

Tags: paraview

I asked this on CFD online but got no responses back. I have been given a bunch of Tecplot (`.plt`) files that I am supposed to analyze. But, I really don't like Tecplot, and would much rather use Paraview. Is there some way I can open these files in Paraview? Or, is there some way to open them in Tecplot and then export them to a format that Paraview is able to handle? I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ParaView supports *.plt, you should just try opening one.

Note that ParaView is modular so depending on how you get it, tecplot support may not be enable (binary plt reader is depending on the VisIt bridge). The official binaries (https://www.paraview.org/download/) supports it.